# How to update resources file in .apk

Tags: android, apk

When creating my (unsigned) apk file, my res/values/ folder disappears when viewing the apk file through an unzipping program. However, the res/drawables and res/layout folders show up. Is there any way to ensure the apk file contains the res/values/ folder?

The main use case I have is updating various values in the resources file located in res/values depending on the customer's needs.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is as intended. The values folder is compile in binary format and you cannot retrieve it. If you need to change something, then you need to repackage everything again.

Comment: so is there any other way to change the source of a resources file other than repackaging?

Comment: No, there's no... why would you need to do so?

Comment: Nope, sdk needs to recompile to make sure everything is still correct. Let's say you used to have R.string.foo and then you remove it, what happens then?

Comment: It's what the customer we're developing for wants (senior design project at university). Thanks for the answers though!

Comment: Don't let the customer dictate implementation.

Answer (score 2):

All XML resources are compiled into binary format for performance reasons. SO you would not be able to see them.